# How to generate an Excel document with multiple worksheets from PHP?

Tags: php, spreadsheet

I want to generate an MS Excel file from PHP. I know one can do something like this:

```
header ( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
header ( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=foo_bar.xls" );
```

But it will generate a file with just one Sheet. What I want is generating a file with multiple sheets. How can I do that? Maybe there's a third party library, but I haven't found too much.

Comment: Just a small note on the wording of your question; you say you're already generating a file with just one sheet, but the code you posted above doesn't generate anything, it only sets up the download of an already existing file. Do you already have a file called foo_bar.xls? Or is there code missing that generates the file with just one Sheet.

Comment: @lucideer I was just showing that I know how to generate an XLS file. Just for avoiding answers that suggest doing what I have already done. Of course, the code that generates the file is complete; I was just showing a fragment of it.

Comment: Just to clarify, I believe what OP meant is that he can stream a CSV file, but with those headers, and it will be disposed of by most browsers as a XLS file.  (I have done this before)  He was not aware of the PHPExcel-type approach in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try looking at [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel). This is a simple example that creates an Excel file with two sheets:

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Create a first sheet, representing sales data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Something');

// Rename sheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Name of Sheet 1');

// Create a new worksheet, after the default sheet
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();

// Add some data to the second sheet, resembling some different data types
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'More data');

// Rename 2nd sheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Second sheet');

// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="name_of_file.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Thanks for editing in an example Cristian. Hope you find the library easy to use

Comment: This library is simply awesome... in fact, I'm want to donate an amount of money. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Christian - I do have a vested interest in sharing: I am one of the main authors :-)

Comment: +1 For you. Thank you Mark Baker. I was searching the same thing.

Comment: Dear @MarkBaker THANK YOU for such an awesome piece of software. You rule.

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker for the example!  Worked like a charm! +1

Comment: @MarkBaker -Thanks for your answer,
If i want to change the storing path of the file, then what i need to change. i.e. i want to save file to particular location in my drive.

Comment: @Vimal - for storing on the server: delete the lines setting headers, and replace 'php://output' in the call to save() with the filepath/filename of your choice.... for telling the browser where the file should be stored if downloaded to the user, forget it - browsers don't work that way and you have no control over where the users chooses to store a file on his own PC

Comment: Hello,
I appreciate your answer but in line `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Something');`

it write on first column and first row, i have dynamic row and colum and want to write. it depends on data in database. So please explain it or let me know documentation of it.

Comment: @user3540050 - In the line `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Something');`, the value `A1` is the Excel cell address (column `A`, row `1`), change `A1` to `B5` to write to column `B` row `5`, etc.... this really is how MS Excel works, not complex rocket science

Comment: @MarkBaker - yes thanks for working on that.  I intend to write a script that will turn a database into a spreadsheet, with each sheet being a table and the sheet itself mimicking the CSV export of the data.

I can do it based on this information, but wondered if your codebase has a faster method to take a 2d array and convert it to a sheet.  Thanks!  This is for office staff to get a quick overview in a format they understand.

Comment: @OliverWilliams - Should really be a new question, but the worksheet has a `fromArray()` method that does what you ask.... however, you're better working a row at a time from the db rather than building large arrays in memory

Comment: @MarkBaker, thanks and I agree.  When I complete the script I'll post as an answered question.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean like have your PHP script create an Excel file, write some stuff to it on any sheet, etc, then offer that up for the client to download, you can just use PHP's built-in COM extension.  See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php for all sorts of examples.  However, you will need Excel (or a clone like OpenOffice) installed on the server.  If you don't, perhaps Mark Baker's answer above will work instead without it.

Comment: I don't believe that Open Office supports COM, I think that's limited to a range of MS applications, which does limit this option to a Windows server. COM is pretty powerful, and very efficient, but sadly not well documented

Comment: @Mark Baker: OpenOffice supports COM.  See: http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Bridge/Automation_Bridge

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, that's very useful to know... I'll have to do some playing with it

Comment: Np.  Mimicking COM on other OS's is possible (XPCOM, CORBA), but it looks painfully complex, and unknown if PHP would even work with those.  I'm sure you can also fake it using WINE.  OSX (http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2004/04/16/com_osx.html?page=1) should work with it out of the box.

Comment: Forgot to mention: I can't find the citation on PHP's manual any longer, but it did suggest not using COM on a server.  This is good advice.  If clients are accessing the same Excel file, corruptions can occur.  If something causes a popup prompt like "Are you sure you want to do this?", the request will hang expecting *the server itself* to click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
<?php
    require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
    require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    //Update the multiple sheets in PHP excel
    $report_file = 'Report_' . date('Y-m-d') . '.xlsx';
    $report_file_exists  = 0;
    //If the file doesnot exist , create new otherwise append the data at last
    if (!file_exists($report_file)) {
        objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    }
    else {
        $report_file_exists = 1;
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($report_file);
    }
    $columns = [
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
        'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
   ];
    //Sheet details
    $sheet_details = [
        //1st sheet details
        0 => [
            'sheet_title'   => 'Products',
            'sheet_heading' => ['Article_Number','Name'],
            'sheet_data'    => ['1234','Pen']
        ],
        //2nd Sheet Details
        1 => [
            'sheet_title'   => 'Categories',
            'sheet_heading' => ['Category Id','Name'],
            'sheet_data'    => [123,'Accessories']
        ]
    ];                      
    $sheet_count = 0;
    $row = 1;
    $column = 0;
    while ($sheet_count <= count($sheet_details)) {
        $objWorkSheet = '';
        if ($report_file_exists == 0) {
            if ($sheet_count > 0) {
                $objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet($sheet_count);
            } 
            else {
                $objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
            }
            $row = 1;
            $column = 0;
            foreach ($sheet_details[$sheet_count]['sheet_heading'] as $head) {
                $objWorkSheet->setCellValue($columns[$column] . $row, $head);
                $column++;
            }
       }
       else {
           $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheet_count);
           $objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet($sheet_count);
       }
       $row = $objWorkSheet->getHighestRow() + 1; //row count
       foreach ($sheet_details[$sheet_count]['sheet_data'] as $report_details) {
           $column = 0;
           foreach ($report_details as $data) {
                $objWorkSheet->setCellValue($columns[$column] . $row, $data);
                $column++;
            }
            $row++;
        }
        $objWorkSheet->setTitle($sheet_details[$sheet_count]['sheet_title']);
        $sheet_count++;
    }
    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
    $objWriter->save($report_file);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("creater");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("Middle field");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Subject");
$objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
$work_sheet_count=3//number of sheets you want to create
$work_sheet=0;
while($work_sheet<=$work_sheet_count){ 
    if($work_sheet==0){
        $objWorkSheet->setTitle("Worksheet$work_sheet");
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($work_sheet)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'SR No. In sheet 1')
            ->getStyle('A1')
            ->getFont()
            ->setBold(true);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($work_sheet)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row++, $i++);//setting value by column and row indexes if needed
    }
    if($work_sheet==1){
        $objWorkSheet->setTitle("Worksheet$work_sheet");
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($work_sheet)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'SR No. In sheet 2')
            ->getStyle('A1')
            ->getFont()
            ->setBold(true);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($work_sheet)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row++, $i++);//setting value by column and row indexes if needed
    }
    if($work_sheet==2){
        $objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet($work_sheet_count);
        $objWorkSheet->setTitle("Worksheet$work_sheet");
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($work_sheet)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'SR No. In sheet 3')
            ->getStyle('A1')
            ->getFont()
            ->setBold(true);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($work_sheet)
            ->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col++, $row++, $i++);//setting value by column and row indexes if needed
    }
    $work_sheet++;
}
$filename='file-name'.'.xls'; //save our workbook as this file name
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache`
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```