# How can I join Excel documents using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, tabs, phpexcel, worksheet

I'm using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to dynamically generate order receipts.

I'd like to be able to generate a "summary" Excel file, containing all the order receipts (one per worksheet).

Is there a way to "join" two (or more) Excel documents into one with PHPExcel ?

Comment: which behavior do you expect? meaningly, how do you want to "join" your files (copy every sheet to one file...)?

Comment: @JMax, yes for example merge doc1.xlsx, doc2.xslx, doc3.xslx into master_doc.xslx (which contains three tabs, one for each file doc1, doc2 and doc3)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Excel, "tabs" are known as "worksheets".  You can create an Excel workbook with multiple worksheets in PHPExcel.

For reference, another answer on SO has [an easy-to-follow guide on how to add additional Worksheets to an existing workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269345/how-to-generate-an-excel-document-with-multiple-worksheets-from-php/3269351#3269351).

[This post on Codeplex](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/257934) has an example of adding an external sheet.  I'm not sure all of the renaming dance is needed though.  (The Codeplex link encourages you to clone the worksheet and copy the cloned sheet so as not to remove it from the original workbook, but I don't think that would be an issue unless you're writing output to the source workbook.)  I think something like this should work:

```
function getReceiptWorksheet( $receiptNumber ) {
    // Do something here to retrieve & return your existing receipt
}

function createMasterWorkbook( $filename, $receiptNumbers ) {
    $workbook= new PHPExcel();

    foreach( $receiptNumbers as $receiptNumber ){
         $worksheet = getReceiptWorksheet( $receiptNumber )
         $workbook->addExternalSheet( $worksheet );
    }

    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($workbook);
    $objWriter->save($filename);
}
```

Then you could just call `createMasterWorkbook( 'receipts.xlsx', array( 1, 2, 3 ) );`.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm with minimum lines of code. PHPExcel is an incredible library!