# PHP export huge excel files

Tags: php, memory, export, phpexcel

I am using [PHPExcel](http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel) class in php to export data from mysql table. The php page simply write the excel data in a loop like:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
# Query result goes to array $result
# ...
$i = 1;
for ($r = 0; $r < count($result); $r++) {
      # Set $value1, $value2, $value3 from $result
      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue("A$i", $value1)
            ->setCellValue("B$i", $value2)
            ->setCellValue("C$i", $value3);
      $i++;
}
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("/path/to/exported_file.xlsx");
```

This code works fine when the exported file is not huge. I was able to export around 10,000 records. However, I am getting the following error when the file becomes bigger (more records are returned from the query).

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes)
```

I increased the memory limit in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` to 1024M. Even after this increase, I am still getting this error.

I tried to create several excel files instead of one by limiting the query results by appending `LIMIT` to the `SELECT` statement, but this also did not solve the problem.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

I am running php-5.2.4 and apache-2.2.8 on ubuntu server if that matters.

Comment: What functionality of Excel file you need to create one? Would not csv be enough? Secondly "xlsx" files tend to be the biggest - could you use binary one (xls or xlsb)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use PHPExcel's cell caching (if you aren't already)
2. Don't populate
   an array by looping through the database query resultset, and then
   populate PHPExcel by looping through that array; populate PHPExcel
   directly by looping through the database query resultset

Comment: I used the 2nd point and exported the files as csv. It is much lighter on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Export your records as multiple excel files and join them together. About joining, there is already a question in [How can I join Excel documents using PHPExcel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286223/how-can-i-join-excel-documents-using-phpexcel)