# Merge Excel files using php

Tags: php, excel, merge

I have two excel files each with a single worksheet.  I want to take the two excel files and create a single excel file with two worksheets.  I would like to do this with PHP.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).  Not sure if it can do what you want though.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286223/how-can-i-join-excel-documents-using-phpexcel

Comment: @Rocket - PHPExcel is quite capable of doing this

Comment: @MarkBaker: Cool, never actually used it, but I figured it was a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com)

```
$inputFileType1 = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName1 = 'inputData1.xlsx';
$inputFileType2 = 'Excel5';
$inputFileName2 = 'inputData2.xls';
$outputFileType = 'Excel5';
$outputFileName = 'outputData.xls';

// Load the first workbook (an xlsx file)
$objPHPExcelReader1 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType1);
$objPHPExcel1 = $objPHPExcelReader1->load($inputFileName1);

// Load the second workbook (an xls file)
$objPHPExcelReader2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType2);
$objPHPExcel2 = $objPHPExcelReader2->load($inputFileName2);

// Merge the second workbook into the first
$objPHPExcel2->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Unique worksheet name');
$objPHPExcel1->addExternalSheet($objPHPExcel2->getActiveSheet());

// Save the merged workbook under a new name (could save under the original name)
// as an xls file
$objPHPExcelWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel1,$outputFileType);
$objPHPExcelWriter->save($outputFileName);
```

Comment: but it doesn't merge chart , try file with chart & graphs and it will remove that

Comment: This library is deprecated now use this: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet