# Export to Excel is dropping leading zero

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I found this code on web for export tables from Mysql to Excel. The problem is that data exported to excel is missing the leading zero. So instead of number 090888 i get 90888. Except that code work fine, so i would like to change this particular code.

If anyone can help with this I would really appreciate it.

The code:

```
header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

/*******Start of Formatting for Excel*******/

//define separator (defines columns in excel & tabs in word)

$sep = "\t"; //tabbed character

//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields

for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++) {

echo mysql_field_name($result,$i) . "\t";

}

print("\n");

//end of printing column names

//start while loop to get data

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $schema_insert = "";

        for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)

        {

            if(!isset($row[$j]))

                $schema_insert .= "NULL".$sep;

            elseif ($row[$j] != "")

                $schema_insert .= "$row[$j]".$sep;

            else

                $schema_insert .= "".$sep;

        }

        $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);

 $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);

        $schema_insert .= "\t";

        print(trim($schema_insert));

        print "\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Does the spreadsheet already exist?  If so, ensure that the columns' formats are set to Text for those columns where the zero is dropping.  Currently they are numeric columns (and so the 0 at the front is superfluous)

Answer (score 0):

When you print it into the excel sheet, precede the numbers by a single quote.
That will **force them to be treated as text, and not as numeric data.**

For example, print `'090888` instead of just `090888`, which will force it to treat it as a string (but will not display the `'` in excel.

Another way would be to adjust formatting, but I don't think that is possible in the above case.

Comment: Adjusting formatting simply isn't possible with a tab-separated-value file

Comment: If `$row[$j]` contains your number, preceded by 0, `$schema_insert .= "'$row[$j]".$sep;`. Note the single quote before the number itself.

Comment: Yes, but then i get like '090888

Comment: @user1758545 - But isn't that what you said you wanted? "So instead of number 090888 i get 90888"? If not, please explain exactly what you do want

Answer (score 0):

You can't add the '0' for integer when creating XLS. because the format of the column is integer only in the Excel you have created. so we need to change the format of the column. for this you can use this package [PHPEXCEL](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) for creating Excel.

and also you can refer this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3269351/1638375

Answer (score 0):

After using PHPEXCEL, use like this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValueExplicit("$row[$j]", "value" ,PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the age of this thread, I would like to add something to it. None of the solutions mentioned above worked for me, but this code will:

```
"="" . $order['phone'] . """;
```

You can use it like this:

```
$orders = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'phone' => '0123456789'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Jane Smith',
        'phone' => '0987654321'
    )
);

// Loop through each order in the array
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    // Output the phone number with leading zeros intact
    echo "=\"" . $order['phone'] . "\"\n";
}
```

This code adds an equals sign (=) followed by two double quotes (") before and after the phone number. This tells Excel to treat the value as text and keep the leading zeros intact.

When you export the data to Excel, the phone number field will be displayed with the leading zeros preserved.